# Descargar imagen o pdf Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

¿Cómo puedo descargar una imagen o un pdf de mis plantillas en Django? al descargar el pdf se abre en otra pestaña y también al intentar descargar una imagen. esto no sucede con otra extensiones como lo son videos o archivos de word.

en los templates hago el llamado a {{% file.image.url %}} pero este no lo descarga si no que me lo muestra en una pestaña

models.py

```
from django.utils import timezo
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
import uuid
# Create your models here.

class Imagenes(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    image = models.FileField(verbose_name='Imagenes' ,upload_to='imagenes', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'])])
    fecha_subida = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Imagenes"
```

views.py

```
def imagelinks(request, id):
    imagen = get_object_or_404(models.Imagenes, id=id)
    descarga = models.Imagenes.objects.filter(id=id)

    data = {"formu":UploadImageForm(instance=imagen), 'descargas':descarga}
    return render(request, 'imagenes/linkimagenes.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from imagenes import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('downloadi/<id>/', views.imagelinks, name="imagenlinks"),
    path('imagenes/', views.SubirImage, name="imagenes")
]
```

en los templates hago el llamado a {{% file.image.url %}} pero este no lo descarga si no que me lo muestra en una pestaña

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %} {% endblock %}

{% block header %} 

<h3 class="float-md-start mb-0"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Archinon</a></h3>
<nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
  <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0"  href="{% url 'archivos' %}">Archivos</a>
  <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="{% url 'imagenes' %}">Imagenes</a>
  <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="{% url 'videos' %}">Videos</a>
</nav>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 

  <main class="px-10">
    <h2>¡Descarga tu Imagen! </h2>
    {% load archivo_tags %}
    {% for file in descargas %}
      <a>{{file.image}}</a>  
      <a href="{{ file.image.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Download ({{ file.image.size|sizify }})</a>
      <h5>No olvide guardar su link:</h5>
      <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
        <a href="{% url 'archilinks' file.id %}" class="alert-link">127.0.0.1:8000{% url 'archilinks' file.id %}</a>
      </div>

    {% endfor%}
  </main>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de resolver este problema es usar el atributo "download", seria de esta manera:

```
<a href="{{ file.image.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" download>Download ({{ file.image.size|sizify }})</a>
```

Solo toma en cuenta que este atributo solo funciona en navegadores relativamente nuevos, puedes ver cuales aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Al final era algo muy sencillo...muchas gracias!